# How to add background shading or major tick marks in R ggplot line graph?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I have a simple ggplot line graph that plots data by month-year(x = month year, y = sum) over the past 2+ years. I want to add background shading for each year to help distinguish the months and seasonality. Is there any way to do this? If not I will settle for major tick marks at each January (2015, 2016, 2017 etc.). In my ideal, the background of the first 12 data points would be one color, the second 12 another color and so on. Ideally this would be future proof as I will continually be adding data to this data frame as time goes on.

[image: my plot]

Comment: You could use `geom_area` with a `fill` based on year to color each year differently.

Comment: Or use `geom_rect` to fill the plot area.

Comment: i tried using geom_area. i created a third column 'year' and tried ......+ geom_area(aes(fill=year)) but i get the error: "Error in f(...) : Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon". i converted the year column to numeric and i still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use `geom_tile()` to plot a layer of coloured rectangles first and then the point and line layers on top:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year_month, y = sum, group = 1)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = stringr::str_sub(year_month, end = 4)),
            width = 1, height = Inf, alpha = 0.3) +
  labs(fill = "year") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

`geom_tile()` uses the `fill` aesthetic to colour the tiles. The colour is derived from extracting the year from the `year_month` variable.

This is achieved by calling the `str_sub()` function from the `stringr` package which
extracts and replaces substrings from a character vector. Besides the character vector, this function takes two parameters `start` and `end` to specify the positions of the first and last character, resp., to be extracted. `start` defaults to `1L` so only the `end` position has to be specified.

If the time series will be extendend in the future the colour scheme will adopt itself automatically as the OP had requested.

The parameter `alpha = 0.3` to `geom_tile()` makes the background colours transparent so that the panel grid lines shine through.

`labs(fill = "year")` is used to rename the legend title conveniently.

### Data

Unfortunately, the OP hasn't provided a reproducible example so it was necessary to prepare own sample data:

```
set.seed(1234)
n_month <- 26
df <- data.frame(
  month = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), length.out = n_month, by = "month"),
  sum = rnorm(n_month, mean = 200000, sd = 50000)
)
df$year_month <- format(df$month, "%Y-%m")

str(df)
#'data.frame':  26 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ month     : Date, format: "2015-01-01" "2015-02-01" "2015-03-01" ...
# $ sum       : num  263119 207351 151471 271626 130593 ...
# $ year_month: chr  "2015-01" "2015-02" "2015-03" "2015-04" ...
```

Comment: one question i did have. what does the end=4 parameter accomplish?

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. According to the help page `?stringr::str_sub`, this function extracts and replaces substrings from a character vector. It is used here to extract the first 4 characters from the `year_mon` variable to get the year. `str_sub` starts at the first character by default, so only `end = 4` had to be specified.